# What is the antonym for the verb "support"?

Tags: antonyms

For example: `I support Bob's decision to quit his job.`

What word could you use in place of support to make that sentence have the opposite meaning?

Comment: "I oppose Bob's decision to quit his job."  "I reject Bob's decision..."  "I abhor Bob's decision..."  Why do you think there is *the* antonym?

Comment: "I am **indifferent** to Bob's decision..." "I **acquiesce** to Bob's decision...", "I **celebrate** Bob's decision...", **object to**, **protest**, **demur**...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depends very much on what you mean by opposite. If you mean that I am against Bob's decision to quit his job, then GEdgar's suggestions, along with [a myriad of synonyms and antonyms from thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/browse/support), will do

> I oppose Bob's decision...
>
> I reject Bob's decision...

However, if you mean that you are not in favor of, but not necessarily against Bob's decision, then it could be

> I don't support Bob's decision...

Comment: I undermine Bob's decision...

Comment: I did mean the first one. I think oppose is the word I was looking for. Sorry for not being clearer.